# Where is Restwell Keep Located?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm getting ready to start a Chaos Scar campaign with my group an I'm having a bit of trouble placing Restwell Keep on the map provided by Wizards.

Where is Restwell Keep located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the consensus of online opinion is: *wherever you want it to be*...so as long as it's outside the King's Wall on the Scar side.

IMHO the number of ideas that place it at a crossroads on maps 1 or 2 miles from the King's Wall, standing in offense and/or defense of the area make, "militarily-speaking," the most natural placement.